# How to override the radio.phtml in custom module?

Tags: magento

I have created a custom module which change the template for the bundle product option, it is in the `radio.phtml`.

I am now overriding the `radio.phtml` on a new theme `xxx/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml`.

But I want to put the `radio.pthml` into my custom module folder, that is
`template/mycompany/mymodule/radio.phtml`

I understand that I can do in the `mymodule.xml` layout by using `<action method="setTemplate">`, but how can I know the `<reference>` name for the `radio.phtml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to rewrite this block because the theme are set in block..

```
Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio
```

you  can in this function

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml');
    }
```

you can rewrite block module like that

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <bundle>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>Spacename_Modulname_Block_Adminhtml_Radio</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>
                </rewrite>
            </bumdle>
        </blocks>
    </global>
```

and call your phtml file

```
class Spacename_Modulname_Block_Adminhtml_Radio extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->setTemplate('test/radio.phtml'); //your file path link here
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the config.xml should be <bundle> </bundle>, not </adminhtml>